# Print application banner when Spring Context starts

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to implement an application Banner that prints the version and other information when our application starts. I have tried implementing SmartLifecycle and ApplicationListener without success.

The callback method never gets called and the banner never prints. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Banner implements ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent>
{
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Banner.class);

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStartedEvent event)
    {
        log.info("*******************************************************");
        log.info("Application v1.8 starting");
        log.info("*******************************************************");
    }
}
```

Comment: My particular use case is a web application but I'd like to write it so that it can be declared as a bean in any spring context and just work. I know spring-boot has a Banner class that can be used but our app doesn't use spring-boot. I also realize that a ContextLoaderListener could be used for a webapp but like I said, I would like it to work in any environment as long as it is declared as a spring bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContextStartedEvent` is raised only when `ConfigurableApplicationContext.start()` method is invoked. Use `ContextRefreshedEvent` instead of `ContextStartedEvent`

**Documentation:**

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events

Comment: Thanks that works! It doesn't print a the very beginning of the startup process but I can live with that. I see other beans initializing first. I suppose I could add a dependsOn attribute to one of my datasource beans if I really want it to happen first.

Answer (score 0):

If you use spring-boot, the below solution will work for you.

Use [ASCII art generator](http://patorjk.com)
OR 
Use [Spring Boot Banner Generator](https://spring-boot-banner-gen.cfapps.io/) ; If you want to use any "image" to generate a banner for your Spring Boot application.

Copy the generated ASCII characters into /src/main/resources/banner.txt

Start the spring-boot application.

Comment: I had a comment under my post stating we don't use spring-boot, at least not in that application. Maybe I should edit my post so it will be obvious for others, sorry about that. Thanks for the suggestion.